# Rails & NLTK deploying to Heroku

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, heroku, nltk, assets

I may be wrong, but I have a Rails app which uses python script with some NLTK dependencies (it was easier to achieve what I wanted with it)...

It works fine locally (python script runs in the background) of course, but not everything is as smooth when I try to deploy it..

Is there any way I can deploy NLTK to heroku?

I know I can put it to vendor/plugins or smth like that, but that will hardly make

```
import nltk
```

in my python script recognize it.

I hope the question is clear enough )

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this, though it will take some customization. You could create a buildpack which both installs your ruby dependencies as well as your python dependencies. It could become some composite of:

https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/

Once it installs the dependencies you just need to ensure your PATH is set to load the appropriate locations.